# how to scrape multipage website with python and export data into .csv file?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the following website using python and need to export scraped data into a CSV file:

http://www.swisswine.ch/en/producer?search=&&

This website consist of 154 pages to relevant search. I need to call every pages and want to scrape data but my script couldn't call next pages continuously. It only scrape one page data.

Here I assign value i<153 therefore this script run only for the 154th page and gave me 10 data. I need data from 1st to 154th page

How can I scrape entire data from all page by once I run the script and also how to export data as CSV file??

my script is as follows

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
i = 0
while i < 153:       
     url = ("http://www.swisswine.ch/en/producer?search=&&&page=" + str(i))
     r = requests.get(url)
     i=+1
     r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print (soup.prettify())


g_data = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "contact-information"})
for item in g_data:
      print(item.text)
```

Comment: The lines that scrape the data: from soup = .... down, should be inside the loop. Otherwise you finish the loop and are getting the data only of the last one after the loop.

Comment: @vishnu It is good to use BeautifulSoup. But if you are looking for whole things to manage well, you should go for http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You should put your HTML parsing code to *under the loop* as well. And you are not incrementing the `i` variable correctly (thanks @MattDMo):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i = 0
while i < 153:       
     url = ("http://www.swisswine.ch/en/producer?search=&&&page=" + str(i))
     r = requests.get(url)
     i += 1 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print (soup.prettify())

    g_data = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "contact-information"})
    for item in g_data:
          print(item.text)
```

I would also improve the following:

- use [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to maintain a web-scraping session, which will also bring a performance boost:

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase
- be explicit about an underlying parser for `BeautifulSoup`:

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")  # or "lxml", or "html5lib"
  ```

Comment: You missed one small detail - in the `while` loop, `i` is incremented as `i =+1`. It should be `i += 1`.

Comment: @MattDMo ah, I felt something wrong about that but lacking morning coffee. Good catch! Thanks.